# Regex pattern for not allowing anything except comma in between

Tags: regex

Could anyone help here !
I need an regular expression where I can get only comma in some couple of Enum values.
For example:

```
 Savings Account,Current Account,Credit card --> valid
 Savings Account --> valid
Savings Account,Credit Card --> valid
Credit Card,Savings Account --> valid
(Space or any special character)Savings Account --> Invalid
Savings Account(space or any special character) --> Invalid
Savings AccountCurrent Account --> Invalid (it should be separated by comma)
```

I have tried this below expression but It is even accepting Savings AccountCurrent Account also.

```
((Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)[,]?)+\b
```

Comment: ((Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)[,]?)+\b

Comment: It should allow only some Enum defined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you go:

```
^(Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)(([,](Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card))*)$
```

Explained:

```
^(Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)  # Starts with one of the Enums defined
(([,](Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card))*)$  # Optionally contains any numbers of defined enums prefixed by `,` and ends
```

If don't want same string to appear twice:

```
^(Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)(,(?!\1)(Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card))?(,(?!\3)(?!\1)(Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card))?$
```

Explained:

```
^(Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)  # Capture group 1, matches one of the defined enums
(,  # start of capture group 2, checks for comma
    (?!\1)  # Negative Lookahead, makes sure it doesn't matches the result of group 1
    (Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)  # Capture group 3, matches one of the defined enums
)?  # end of capture group 2, make stuff inside it optional
(,  # start of capture group 4, checks for comma
    (?!\3)  # Negative Lookahead, makes sure it doesn't matches the result of group 3
    (?!\1)  # Negative Lookahead, makes sure it doesn't matches the result of group 1
    (Savings Account|Current Account|Credit Card)  # Capture group 5, matches one of the defined enums
 )?$  # end of capture group 4, make stuff inside it optional
```

Comment: Hi Vibhav.. Can we restrict these values for only one time.. For example if I am giving Savings Account,Savings Account it is accepting ..Can we restrict it only for one time. Recurring only once per.

Comment: Updated my answer, it's working for me, but test it with a couple of different cases yourself.